# How to change button action and title for user and guest user dynamically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

There are two users in my app one is guest user and other is logged in user. I have set button actions in home view controller as register and sign in if the user is not logged in. Now i want to change the button title and action in setting viewController to edit profile and log out if the user is logged in already.I have logout function in home viewController how can i access this function in setting viewController. Here is my code.

How i can perform action and change button userRegister to Edit Profile and sign in to logout out dynamically when user is already logged in.

```
HomeViewController.swift

func performlogOut(){ }
```

In setting viewController

```
@IBAction func userRegistration(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registerUser") as!  registerUser

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
}

  @IBAction func signIn(_ sender: Any) {
    
   
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as!  SignInViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two buttons and hide one of them depending on the situation.

```
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var editProfileButton: UIButton!

...

var isLoggedIn: Bool

...

loginButton.isHidden = isLoggedIn
editProfileButton.isHidden = !isLoggedIn
```

Software design-wise it's better to have two buttons because you separate the responsibilities.

Comment: ok have two separate buttons and no issue for edit profile but how can i perform logout as my logout function is in home viewcontroller how i can access it in setting viewcontroller?

Comment: @Sipa There are various ways, here's one: Create a class that handles login/logout and move all that logic into there, then pass a reference to your settings view controller.